# SQL QUERY JOIN with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Sorry for this question, but I can't find a solution to this simple problem.

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE A  
R_ID integer  
CID1 integer  
CID2 integer  
CID3 integer
CID4 integer 



TABLE C   
CID integer  
NAME varchar(50)
```

what I'm trying to do is a query that will output, for every table A row, the name of `CID1`,  `CID2` and so on, considering that `CID1` has always a value, `CID2`, `CID3` and `CID4` could be `NULL`, I can't use `UNION` and in my s

This is my starting point:

```
SELECT a.R_ID, c.NAME
FROM A a, C c
WHERE (a.CID1 = c.CID or a.CID2 = c.CID or a.CID3 = c.CID or a.CID4 = c.CID)
```

But as you can see, it only works if all `CID`s are valued, otherwise some results will have a blank `NAME` field.

Any tip on how to remove unwanted rows will be really appreciated.

EDIT :
I have to print a list of: Room # - name of the student in that room, so the outputted table must be in the form : `R_ID`, `NAME`

Suppose:

```
TABLE A  
1,1,2,NULL,NULL  
2,3,NULL,NULL,NULL  
3,4,NULL,NULL,NULL

TABLE B  
1, Mark  
2, John  
3, Steve  
4, Nick
```

My target is to obtain a table like this:

```
R_ID - NAME  
1 - Mark  
1 - John  
2 - Steve  
3 - Nick
```

What I got is:

```
1 - Mark  
1 - John  
1 -   
1 -   
2 - Steve  
2 -   
2 -   
2 -   
3 - Nick  
3 -   
3 -  
3 -
```

The solution of 4 LEFT JOINs is not applicable because I can't use NAME1,NAME2 and so on, but only 1 field NAME.

A query like:

```
SELECT r.R_ID, c.NAME 
FROM A a LEFT JOIN C c on a.CID1 = c.CID
LEFT JOIN C as c1 on a.CID2 = c1.CID
LEFT JOIN C as c2 on a.CID3 = c2.CID
LEFT JOIN C as c3 on a.CID4 = c3.CID
```

will output:

```
1 - Mark
2 - Steve
3 - Nick
```

The solution `NAME is not NULL`  works perfectly on SQLFiddle, but still presents rows with no name on my `mysql 5.5.15` (also tried on firebird 2.5, the only other DB Server I've on my pc, but with the same result)

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns a name for every `cid` value, see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd8429/2)

What might be an issue are empty or `NULL` entries in the `name` columns, see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccdf0/1)

You can fix this with a simple join on tables `a` and `c` and an additional `where` clause

```
select a.r_id, c.name
from a
join c on c.cid in (a.cid1, a.cid2, a.cid3, a.cid4)
where c.name is not null
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccdf0/2)

Of course, you can achieve the same with your implicit join by adding the same clause

```
SELECT a.R_ID, c.NAME
FROM A a, C c
WHERE (a.CID1 = c.CID or a.CID2 = c.CID or a.CID3 = c.CID or a.CID4 = c.CID)
      and c.name is not null
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccdf0/3)

If you have empty strings instead of `NULL` values, you can wrap `name` in [`trim`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to cope with whitespace too

```
and trim(c.name) <> ''
```

Comment: SOLVED with your solution but with this strange change: `and c.name <> ''` in this way works perfectly both on mysql and firebird

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 separate joins for each CID column in TableA.

```
SELECT
  R_ID,

  c1.Name As CID1Name,
  c2.Name As CID2Name,
  c3.Name As CID3Name
FROM
  TableA a
  LEFT JOIN TableC c1 ON a.CID1 = c1.CID
  LEFT JOIN TableC c2 ON a.CID2 = c2.CID
  LEFT JOIN TableC c3 ON a.CID3 = c3.CID
```

Comment: After removing the bugs, it still returns `NULL` entries, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd8429/5

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you mean you don't want any row where Name is NULL? Wouldn't that return only the first row?